# Deciding on a database structure for pricing wizard

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql, database-design

### Option A

We are working on a small project that requires a pricing wizard for custom tables. (yes, actual custom tables- the kind you eat at. From here out I'll call them kitchen tables so we don't get confused) I came up with a model where each kitchen table part was a database table. So the database looked like this:

```
TableLineItem
-------------
ID
TableSizeID
TableEdgeWoodID
TableBaseID
Quantity

TableEdgeWoodID
---------------
ID
Name
MaterialUnitCost
LaborSetupHours
LaborWorkHours
```

Each part has to be able to calculate its price. Most of the calculations are very similar. I liked this structure because I can drag it right into the linq-to-sql designer, and have all of my classes generated. (Less code writing means less to maintain...) I then implement a calculate cost interface which just takes in the size of the table. I have written some tests and this functions pretty well. I added also added a table to filter parts in the UI based on previous selections. (You can't have a particular wood with a particular finish.) There some other one off exceptions in the model, and I have them hard coded. This model is very rigid, and changing requirements would change the datamodel. (For example, if all the tables suddenly need umbrellas.)

### Option B:

After various meetings with my colleagues (which probably took more time than it should considering the size of this project), my colleagues decided they would prefer a more generic approach. Something like this:

```
Spec
----
SpecID
SpecTypeID
TableType_LookupID
Name
MaterialUnitCost
LaborSetupHours
LaborWorkHours

SpecType 
--------
SpecTypeID
ParentSpecType_SpecTypeID
IsCustomerOption
IsRequiredCustomerOption
```

etc...

This is a much more generic approach that could be used to construct any product. (like, if they started selling chairs...) I think this would take longer time to implement, but would be more flexible in the future. (although I doubt we will revisit this.) Also you lose some referential integrity- you would need triggers to enforce that a table base cannot be set for a table wood.

### Questions:

1. Which database structure do you prefer? Feel free to suggest your own.
2. What would be considered a best practice? If you have several similar database tables, do you create 1 database table with a type column, or several distinct tables? I suspect the answer begins with "It depends..."
3. What would an estimated time difference be in the two approaches (1 week, 1 day, 150% longer, etc)

Thanks in advance. Let me know if you have any questions so I can update this.

Answer (score 3):

Having been caught out much more often than I should have by designing db structures that met my clients original specs but which turned out to be too rigid, I would always go for the more flexible approach, even though it takes more time to set up.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have time for a complete answer right now, but I'll throw this out:

- It's usually a bad idea to design a database based on the development tool that you're using to code against it.
- You want to be generic **to a point**. Tables in a database should represent something and it is possible to make it too generic. For example, a table called "Things" is probably too generic.
- It may be possible to make constraints that go beyond what you expect. Your example of a "table base" with a "table wood" didn't make sense to me, but if you can expand on a specific example someone might be able to help with that.
- Finally, if this is a small application for a single store then your design is going to have much less impact on the project outcome than it would if you were designing for an application that would be heavily used and constantly changed. This goes back to the "too generic" comment above. It is possible to overdesign a system when its use will be minimal and well-defined. I hope that makes sense.

Given your comment below about the table bases and woods, you could set up a table called TableAttributes (or something similar) and each possible option would be of a particular table attribute type. You could then enforce that any given option is only used for the attribute to which it applies all through foreign keys.

Comment: For example, an ikea desk can either have a "A" shape legs, or "T" shape legs. These would be similar to a table base. The wood of the desk can be beige, black, or white. These are similar to the Table Wood.

Comment: Thanks though, very similar to the conculsion we reached: are we being too generic for a small project? I think so, my colleagues defer. I think we can better spend our time elsewhere :p

Answer (score 1):

There is a tendency to over-abstract with database schema design, because the cost of change can be high. Myself, I like table names that are fairly descriptive. I often equate schema design with OO design. E.g., you wouldn't normally create a class named Thing, you would probably call it Product, Furniture, Item, something that relates to your business.

In the schema you have provided there is a mix of the abstract (spec) and the specific (TableType_LookupID). I would tend to equalize the level of abstraction, so use entities like:

```
ProductGroup (for the case where you have a product that is a collection of other products)
Product
ProductType
ProductDetail 
ProductDetailType
etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what my experience would tell me:

1. **Which database structure do you prefer?**  Without a doubt, I'd go for approach one.  Go for the simplest setup that might work.  If you add complexity, always ask yourself, what value will it have to the customer?
2. **What would be considered a best practice?** That does indeed depend, among others on the size of the project and the expected rate of change. As a general rule, generic tables are worth it when you expect the customer to be adding new types. For example, if your customer wants to be able to add a new "color" entity to the table, you'd need generic tables. You can't predict beforehand what they will add.
3. **What would an estimated time difference be in the two approaches?** Not knowing your business, skill, and environment, it's impossible to give a [valid estimate](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735605351). The approach that you are confident in coding will take the least time. Here, my guess would be approach #1 could be 5x-50x as fast. Generic tables are hard, both on the database and the client side.

Answer (score 1):

Option B..

**Generic is generally better than specific.**  Software already is doomed to fail or reach it's capacity by it's design for a certain set of tasks only.  If you build something generic it will break less if abstracted with a realistic analysis of where it might head.  As long as you stay away from over-abstraction and under-abstraction, it's probably the sweet spot.

In this case the adage "less code is more" would probably be drawn in that you wouldn't have to come back and re-write it again.